# How to build an observable which calls multiple observables based on previous result?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have one endpoint which returns `{ ids: [1, 2, 3, 45] }`.

And another one which returns a value for a given id: `{ id: 3, value: 30, active: true }`.

I'm trying to construct an observable which calls the first endpoint and for each id returned call the second enpoint and emits the sum of all `active = true` values:

```
private getIds(group: string) {
  const url = '...';
  return this.http.get<{ ids: number[] }>(url, { params: { group } });
}

private getValue(id: number) {
  const url = '...';
  return this.http.get<ActiveValue>(url, { params: { id: id.toString() } });
}

public getSum(group: string) {
  let sum = 0;
  const bSubject = new BehaviorSubject(sum);

  const observables = this.getIds(group).pipe(
    mergeMap(({ ids }) => ids),
    map(id => this.getValue(id).pipe(tap(({ value, active }) => {
      if (active) {
        sum += value;
        bSubject.next(sum);
      }
    })))
  );

  const observable = forkJoin(observables).pipe(map(() => sum));
  return { bSubject, observable };
}

interface ActiveValue {
  value: number;
  active: boolean;
}
```

But it complains about:

```
forkJoin is deprecated: Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead (deprecation)
```

Also, when I hover over `observables` it shows:

```
const observables: Observable<Observable<ActiveValue>>
```

...while I thought it should be `Observable<ActiveValue>[]`

How can I make it work?

Comment: "while I thought it should be Observable<ActiveValue>[]" Can you explain your thought process to come to that conclusion? And why you constructed your pipe the way you did? (You seem to having misunderstood mergeMap and map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not shure but you may try something like this

```
interface ActiveValue {
    value: number;
    active: boolean;
}

function countActiveValues(values: ActiveVale[]) {
    return values.reduce((acc, { value, active }) => acc + active ? value : 0, 0)
}

class MyClass {
    private getIds(group: string) {
        const url = '...';
        return this.http.get < { ids: number[] } > (url, { params: { group } });
    }

    private getValue(id: number) {
        const url = '...';
        return this.http.get < ActiveValue > (url, { params: { id: id.toString() } });
    }

    private getRequests(ids: number[]) {
        return ids.map((id) => this.getValue(id));
    }

    public getSum(group: string) {
        return this.getIds(group).pipe(
            map(({ ids }) => this.getRequests(ids)),
            switchMap((requests) => forkJoin(requests)),
            map((results) => countActiveValues(result))
        );
    }
}
```

And don't forget to catchError for your requests ;)

Comment: Thank you, it's working now... Its kind of counter-intuitive, I need to read some more times the rxjs docs to get those things right in my head

Comment: RxJS is pretty difficult concept when you hit upon it first time, but with practice it's become more clear =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, value: 30, active: true },
  { id: 2, value: 10, active: false },
  { id: 3, value: 5, active: true },
  { id: 45, value: 1, active: false }
]

function getIds(group) {
    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        const resp = { ids: [1, 2, 3, 45] }
       resolve(resp.ids);
     }, 100);
   });
   return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)
   
}

function getValue(id) {
        const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       resolve(data.find(x => x.id == id));
     }, 100);
   });
   return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)
}

const reduceSum = (acc, {active, value}) => acc += active ? value : 0

function getSum(group) {
  return this.getIds(group)
    .mergeMap(ids => {
        return Rx.Observable.from(ids)
        .mergeMap(id => this.getValue(id))
        .reduce(reduceSum, 0)
    })
}

getSum().subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.12/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```